# Configuring nginx to work with wildfly with proxypass

Tags: nginx, networking, proxy, https, http

I want to configure my nginx config in such a way that non https upgrades to https and then the proxy pass should go to https://ip:8443/SOMECONTEXT/

How can I achieve it

This is the config I am using

```
server {
    listen  ip:80;
    server_name  subdomain1.example.com subdomain2.example.com;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/subdomain1.example.com_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/subdomain1.example.com_error.log warn;
    
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        default_type "text/plain";
        root /var/www/html;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host/$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen  ip:443;
    server_name subdomain1.example.com subdomain2.example.com;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/subdomain1.example.com_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/subdomain1.example.com_error.log warn;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header  Host $host;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass https://ip:8443/;
        proxy_connect_timeout       6000;
        proxy_send_timeout          6000;
        proxy_read_timeout          6000;
        send_timeout                6000;
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a reason why you bind not to all interfaces?

Comment: @djdomi I didn't understand what you mean by bind to interfaces.
I have many domains that will forward to other ports in proxy

Comment: you use   listen  ip:443; <- your are missing   listen  ip:443 ssl; however you could just use   listen  443 ssl; in case you want to use ssl